# Duplicates in data table should be skipped

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

Here the below is the input text file. I am accessing it through data table as shown in the below code.

Input file has the following data:

```
ABC
D
E
F
1234
2345
2345
BAC
A
B
C
2345
ABC
D
E
F
12345
```

I would like to get the following output :

```
ABC
D
E
F
1234
2345
2345
12345
BAC
A
B
C
2345
```

Here is the code which I am trying to execute to get the above output through data table or data set.

```
class Program
{
    private string dirCSV = @"C:\Prod.txt";
    // load the file in the data in the data set
    public DataSet loadCVS()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {

            string connString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Text;", Path.GetDirectoryName(dirCSV));
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Prod.txt", conn);
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            DA.Fill(DT);
            DT.DefaultView.Sort = "Item/Variant ASC";
            conn.Close();
        }     
        catch (Exception e){ /*Error*/}

        return ds;
    }
}
```

Here it will be used:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program obj = new Program();
    obj.loadCVS();
}
```

However I got the data in data table but I am unable to sort the date as shown in the  output in above format.

Can you please help in this? Any ideas?

Comment: Could you fix the formatting on the code sample?

Comment: Refine your question, are your trying to eliminate duplicate, sort the data or trying to sort a dataset with date.

Comment: Why are you even doing that? I mean if you need to read content from a file, use a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287534(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**To avoid Duplicate Record just use `Distinct` in your Query** ***it will give distinct Records...***

```
SELECT Distinct FieldName from Prod.txt
```

**If you want to remove the duplicates in DATA TABLE then try the below code**

```
conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Prod.txt", conn);
DataTable DT = new DataTable();
DA.Fill(DT);
DT.DefaultView.Sort = "Item/Variant ASC";
Hashtable tempTable = new Hashtable();
ArrayList duplicateList = new ArrayList();
foreach (DataRow drow in DT.Rows)
 {
  if (tempTable.Contains(drow[yourcolName]))
     duplicateList.Add(drow);
  else
     tempTable.Add(drow[colName], string.Empty); 
 }
//Removes the duplicates from Datatable...
foreach (DataRow dRow in duplicateList)
  DT.Rows.Remove(dRow);

ds.Tables.Add(DT);
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Thank You soo much Pandian..Your code is working fine however in the required Output isABC D E F 1234 2345 2345 12345 BAC A B C 2345 when i run your code the output is showing as shown belowABC D E F 1234 2345 2345 BAC A B C 2345 12345

iwant 12345 this number below the ABC group.Which is not happening now.Can you please help me in this .